# Obtaining Table metadata from mysql in java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-connector

Is there a way to get table metadata before first executing select query on the table?

Restated: Is there a way to get the column size of a specific row and column of data for the numeric types: int, tinyint, bigint, etc?

```
DatabaseMetaData md = connection.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = dbmd.getColumns(null, null, tableName, "%");
```

I can't use the above code as the `COLUMN_SIZE` for numeric type(`int,tinyint,bigint,etc`) will return the maximum allowed size for these types. I need to get the columnDisplaySize.

The above code will return 10 for `int(8)`, but I need 8 which I can get from resultMetaData of a table.

So is there a way to do this without running a select statement first.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to check into what the INFORMATION_SCHEMA table within MySQL is capable of giving you.  Sometimes you can use them to your advantage.  I did some quick looking and nothing hit me immediately from within there.

MySQL Information Schema: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-schema.html

Answer (score 2):

As @technocrat said, check this query on information_schema

**SELECT column_name, column_type FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where table_schema='[Table schema]' and table_name='[Table Name]'**

Answer (score 1):

Refer below article:

Will help you to know understand an example from JDBC Metadata Get table

http://roseindia.net/jdbc/Jdbc-meta-data-get-tables.shtml

Comment: I know i can get the metadata from the resultset after running select query, but I want to know if there is any other way other then running the select query on the table.

Answer (score 1):

I may be off the mark with what you're asking but is mysql command `show columns in <tablename>` of any use? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-columns.html for more info.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of `INT(8)`, you should know that the 8 is not a size limit.  That's a frequent misconception by MySQL users.  The argument to INT-like data types is only a hint to SQL to pad the values if they have fewer digits than the argument.  It's normally used only for ZEROFILL.

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( i1 INT(8) ZEROFILL, i2 INT(16) ZEROFILL );
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1234, 1234);
SELECT * FROM foo;
+----------+------------------+
| i1       | i2               |
+----------+------------------+
| 00001234 | 0000000000001234 | 
+----------+------------------+
```

The value 8 vs. 16 does not change the storage space required by an INT, nor the range of values it supports.  The INT data type is always 32-bits, and always allows values from -2<sup>31</sup> to 2<sup>31</sup>-1, regardless of the argument you give it.

Likewise TINYINT is always 8 bits, SMALLINT is always 16 bits, MEDIUMINT is always 24 bits, and BIGINT is always 64 bits.

The 10 value you get is the numeric precision, not a size limit.  That is, a 32-bit value may use up to 10 digits when displayed in base-10:

```
SELECT LENGTH(POW(2,31));
+-------------------+
| LENGTH(POW(2,31)) |
+-------------------+
|                10 | 
+-------------------+
```