# Getting a table's metadata without using resultset in java

Tags: java, jdbc

Is there any way to get the meta-data of a particular table even before executing select
statement.

Comment: You can execute a trivial select like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE 0 = 1`

Comment: What you mean "meta-data of a particular table"? Columns properties?

Comment: `connection.getMetaData();` see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html

Comment: @CAMOBAP yes. I want to get the column names of a particular table.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
DatabaseMetaData md = connection.getMetaData();
```

You can learn a lot about tables from this [`DatabaseMetaData`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) interface.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951053/obtaining-table-metadata-from-mysql-in-java?rq=1